# Change font in "Lucida Console"

Tags: c++, fonts

How to change font in console c++ application in  "Lucida Console"? 
In program, but not manual. My operation system - windows. Environment - Code Blocks.

Comment: See [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Simple I include Wincon.h and  Windows.h , but I get compillar error "SetCurrentConsoleFontEx' was not declared in this scope|"

Comment: @Tapac Only include Windows.h and it works.

Comment: @Simple I only include Windows.h, but it does not work

Comment: @Tapac I don't know what to tell you. `#include <Windows.h> int main() { SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(nullptr, false, nullptr); }` This program compiles. Check what `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined as.

Comment: @Simple You ,probably, work in Visual Studio. I work in Code  Blocks . I can not use this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use 
`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(nullptr, false, nullptr)` which is located in `<Windows.h>`.

If this does not work, It's not because of your IDE (Code::blocks) but because of you compiler. MinGW is the default compiled with Code::blocks but It does not support this function.

You just have to change your compiler to MSVS 2010 for example and It should work perfectly :).